# Junit4 Android TestField text test

Tags: junit4, android-testing

My test is:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class TipActivityTests {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<TipActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(TipActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void initialValues() {
        onView(withId(R.id.tip_label_base_price)).check(matches(ViewMatchers.withText("45"")));
    }
}
```

But I get the error `'with text: is "45"' doesn't match the selected view. Expected: with text: is "45"`:

```
android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'with text: is "45"' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: with text: is "45"
Got: "AppCompatTextView{id=2131689669, res-name=tip_label_base_price, visibility=VISIBLE, width=266, height=106, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=141.0, y=96.0, text=$ 45.00, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"
```

It doesn't make sense to me, it should not print the actual value of the field vs the compared value?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and spent quite some time trying to understand the root cause. It turned out the strings were not equals, that's why it was failing. The error message is not really explicit because it's printing the whole object properties etc instead of saying: `expected: "foo", received: "bar"`. But the strings are actually compared.

Comment: Yeah, you can see in the print `text="real_text"` but it´s horrible!

Answer (score 2):

As per @mbmc answers, the error message is not too important in this scenario. The test is failing as you're expecting to get `45` but your textview actually has the value of `45.00`. If you make your test pass it should get the text from the textview correctly.